# Symfony2 - Why use XML for settings/config?

Tags: xml, symfony, yaml, configuration-files

Is there any interest to use XML over YAML for each of these types of file:

- config
- security
- routing
- services
- translations

I would like to ask XML vs YAML and JSON globally, but I'll stick to these topics :)

Comment: Such a common question since we know that Symfony 2 will handle many formats for settings/config :)

Comment: I'm asking because I'm wondering why people still use XML

Comment: Good question. I was wondering about this myself. There was also one ini-file (`parameters.ini`) in 2.0, which is renamed to `yml` in 2.1.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In my company projects for each of mentioned above points we use `YAML` because it is more readable. The most readable. **The readablest.**

---

**EDIT**:

The only abstract situation I can imagine for using `XML` over `YAML` - is probably for some dynamic file writers, since it is easier to manipulate with nodes using `SimpleXML` or something like that. For example, if you need to define some configuration file, build schemas in tests etc...

But it is hard to imagine another situation.

---

**ANOTHER EDIT:**

Since my answer was accepted, I cannot disagree with [m2mdas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1218997/m2mdas) - as he mentioned in his [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11747193/970721), another thing that makes sense for using `XML` is IDE's autocompletion support.

Comment: I can't agree more with you. That's why I'm wondering why use XML ? I still can see recent examples using XML to describe this type of data...

Comment: Probably for some dynamic file writers - it is easier to manipulate with nodes using `SimpleXML` or something like that. For example, if you need to define some configuration file in tests... It is hard to imagine another situation

Answer (score 10):

Advantage of xml congiruration is IDE auto-complete and instant validation. As elements defined by concrete schema definition, IDEs can instantly validate elements against it which is not possible in YAML or JSON. Also I think Symfony validates the xml elements in configuration against the definition before processing it.

**Edit:**

By validation I meant validate the element structure against the defined schema. It is better to validate the configuration before processing it. For example a `services.yml` with hundreds service object definition have an error in 99th service definition. Yaml parser will parse incrementally, create expensive cpu intensive service objects and will fail at 99th definition. Whereas for `service.xml` with defined schema you can validate the element structure and process them if it is OK. Obviously second process is efficient.

Comment: Could you give an example ? I imagine a lot of validation is required for XML, but with YAML it should be simpler isn't it ? Also YAML will need less autocomplete because there are only key/values.

Comment: Ok I see, however I imagine hundreds of services should be quite hard to read by humans in XML...

Comment: Well there is a trade-off in every choice :). This is where IDE tooling is important. In java you can easily switch back and forth between service definition and class. PHP IDEs don't have these features right now.

Comment: @MunMunDas Maybe it was true in 2012 but now we have PhpStorm + Symfony plugin which is capable of such things :)

Answer (score 8):

Fabien Potencier wrote about the advantages of using XML over YAML on his blog:

> - When a XML file is loaded, it is automatically validated with the    built-in services.xsd file;
> - The XML can be auto-completed in IDEs;
> - The XML format is faster than the YAML one;
> - The XML format as no external dependencies (the YAML format relies on    the sfYAML component).

Although this post was written for symfony1.x, the points also can definitely be applied for Symfony2.

http://fabien.potencier.org/article/15/symfony-service-container-using-xml-or-yaml-to-describe-services

Answer (score 2):

Another thing in favor of XML is the possibility to define parameters using a PHP constant, which is not possible with YAML.

Comment: in Symfony 3.2 is possible to use PHP constants in YAML: https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-2-php-constants-in-yaml-files