# What is the recommended Symfony2 configuration method?

Tags: configuration, symfony

The cookbook doesn't seem to have a preference, although YAML is shown be default. I was just wondering if there is a standard configuration format or whether it was a completely personal choice?

My main worry is that I choose one format then get half way down the line and find out that all other Symfony developers are using another format, I am limited in some way by my choice or there is a performance implication.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11741947/970721 this question may be interesting for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's personal choice, although on most sites yaml is the default and also the symfony standard package is delivered with yaml.

Besides some bundles use xml, which is not that easy to read, but you get support through the defined schema.

I prefer yaml in the config, because there is a lot in it and it helps me to keep an overview.

Answer (score 1):

YAML for applications and XML for shared bundles.