# What is the difference of JSON and YAML in Symfony?

Tags: php, json, symfony, yaml

I'm new in Symfony2, and i'm studing it about.
But i've observed that Symfony sometimes uses json for some data, and in other situations as routing uses yaml filetype.
What is the difference in that framework? why use one instead of another?
They are very similar in the syntax, why not only one (json or yml)?
i need a very simple explanation.
Thank you!

Comment: There’s no reason. Different horses for courses.

Comment: A similar question was asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11741947/symfony2-why-use-xml-for-settings-config.

My personal experience is that YAML is the way to go for transfiguration. It is easy to read and maintain. As far as ajax and controller usage json is better. Just depends on when/where you use it

Comment: Are you perhaps talking about composer.json?  That file belongs to composer and is not part of the Symfony framework.  You won't find any Symfony specific json files.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say that in this scenario YAML is normally used for internal configuration files due to its readability, while JSON is mostly used for APIs and ajax requests due to the simplicity of format and the client side language used (JavaScript).

However, this is **not a rule**. You could use both formats for the opposite purposes.

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference between the different format. Fabien Potencier talk about this at the Laracon 2013 [here](http://youtu.be/0erGiEm07b8?t=53m25s)